# Custom authorization depending on user property

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In my application, after the user has been logged for the first time, he has to change his default password. For this process I have a `changepassword.xhtml` page where he can change the password. I would like to restrict the access to another page and redirect him to `changepassword.xhtml` until he has changed his default password. The user class has a `firstTime` property where I have register if this is the first time he is logged or not.

Can I manage this in my config class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have to add the `USER_NEED_CHANGE_PASSWORD_ROLE` role to the user  and give him access only to the password change page. Also need to be stored in the base of the flag of the password change and to implement `authentication-success-handler-ref = "my_handler"`.

When the user has successfully held the first authorization, check the status of this flag. If the flag requires a password change then redirect to the password change page. After changing the password redirect him to the login page.